# Docker pass command-line arguments

Tags: python, docker

I really just want to pass an argument via `docker run`
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

# set a directory for the app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy all the files to the container
COPY . .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 5000

# run the command
CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

My python file:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

I tried:

`docker run myimage foo`

I got an error:

```
  flask-app git:(master) ✗ docker run myimage foo
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"foo\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write *foo* at the end of your *docker run* command then you overwrite whole command. Therefore instead of

```
python app.py
```

you call

```
foo
```

Proper way of calling your script with arguments is:

```
docker run myimage python app.py foo
```

Alternatively you may use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD and then your *docker run* command may contain just *foo* after image name

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

# set a directory for the app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy all the files to the container
COPY app.py .

# run the command
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "./app.py"]
```

calling it:

```
docker run myimage foo
```